# Registering a database on Arcgis with operating system authentication

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, sqlite

I have a ArcGIS server and ArcMap on the same machine.  I have a sql database that I have been using on ArcMap that I would like to register with the server for the purpose of publishing services.

When I try to register the database I get the error "Machine:machine name[Servername: The connection property set was missing a required property or the value was unrecognized.  Bad login user]

However the domain\administrator account is registered with the server in ArcCatalog.  How do I get the server to acknowledge the database user?

Answer (score 1):

OS authentication is tricky in this case, because the ArcGIS Server service isn't necessarily running with that same user, and it's the process spawned by AGS that's doing the actual queries.

There are very good reasons to ***avoid*** using highly privileged users for publishing services.  Best practice is to use a minimally privileged (read-only when possible) "service" user (**not** the table owner or database administrator) for database connections, so that zero-day overflow exploits can't destroy database contents.

Answer (score 0):

the service account that is running arcgis server should be added to the the data_reader role for the database you are wishing to register/connect via ArcGIS server.